# Is there a way to use tabset for finished R markdown files

Tags: r, tabs, output, markdown

So I have 17 completely independent R markdown files. They run fine. However, I want to consolidate them into one and have a tabset so that the user can pick one and not all 17.

now, I know how to use tabset inside of each r markdown file. As an example, I create a lot of the charts have four iterations of it and so I use tabset to let the user pick which iteration. In this case, each iteration is based on a numerical threshold for employment.

as an example, I created two generic R markdowns and named test1 and test2. Using a third R markdown file (again, just file>new>R Markdown), how would I reference test1 and test2 in a tabset?

Comment: This seems a little unclear (and, lacking an example, a bit hypothetical). You want to combine 17 already-rendered rmarkdown files into the rmarkdown-equivalent of iframes in a single document? Or are you asking how to rewrite your process to include child documents within each tab of the tabset? I think this would benefit from an example given 2-3 independent rmd docs to form one with 2-3 tabs.

Comment: in this case you can design a wordpress like website, create the pages as you want (in tabsets) and upload the rmarkdown files for refrences (urls) so that you click one particular tab, it opens the referenced URL (and a particular rmarkdown page)..

Comment: @r2evans, how would I save an example of this. Was not aware that you could attach documents to this.  For clarity, I want to use the standard R markdown document that one gets by clicking file>new file>R markdown>html. So produce 3 of them (knitting/rendering each one) and then basically nesting the first two inside the third.

Comment: Tim, for a complete and reproducible question, it would be nice to provide austere examples such as the `sub_*.Rmd` documents I provided in my answer. Many answerers are either short on time or perhaps just lazy, so it makes a lot of sense to make it as easy as possible to "just try something". The keys: simple, short, reproducible, etc. Hope the answer helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no automated way to do it, but here's a hack using HTML iframes (for better or worse).

Up front, two assumptions:

- all HTML files need to be complete, and if they are not "self-contained" then all paths (relative or absolute) must work for the parent HTML document as well; and
- there can be a clear naming convention or known list of files to include; for here, I make all subordinate files named `sub_*.html` so that the parent document can find them easily, but there are many ways this part can be adjusted. As long as `htmlfiles` below can be generated smartly, you're good.

### Create subordinate "pages"

I'll name this `sub_base.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "base"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
plot(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars, pch = 16)
```
````

Name: `sub_ggplot2.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "ggplot2"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point()
```
````

### Parent document

I'll name it `combine.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "combined"
output: html_document
---

# Different Graphics {.tabset}

```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
htmlfiles <- list.files(".", pattern = "sub.*\\.html$", full.names = TRUE)
for (html in htmlfiles) {
  hdr <- gsub("^sub_", "", tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(html)))
  cat(
    sprintf('## %s\n\n <iframe src="%s" title="%s frame" style="position:absolute;height:60%%;width:60%%;"></iframe>\n\n',
            hdr, html, hdr)
  )
}
```
````

The key is that you first need a header that includes the `{.tabset}` style applied to it, and then the loop needs to generate unique sub-headers. This can be done with a `##` followed by subordinate `###`, over to you and the rest of the combine document structure/aesthetics.

### Render

```r
rmarkdown::render("sub_base.Rmd")
rmarkdown::render("sub_ggplot2.Rmd")
rmarkdown::render("combine.Rmd")
```

### Results

You may want to tune the `iframe` components to suit your needs, but they do present scrollbars when pages are large enough.

[image: browser tab showing iframed tabsets]

### Files Sizes

In this example, I kept the default behavior of making the HTML files self-contained. With barely anything in the reports and two plots, this results in a distribution of 2.3M. This has the advantage that you need only distribute the single file: one `combine.html` is rendered, it has the contents of the subordinate documents embedded.

If you need to (for whatever reason) keep any of this not self-contained, then the distribution will change: in addition to needing multiple files and subdirs, the overall size is also larger: 12M for this example. (In this case, you would need to distribute all `sub_*.html` files and `sub_*_files/` subdirs.)